# Detect that the client went offline while sending SSE events through Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, netty, server-sent-events

Using Spring Webflux with Netty, the code below sends heartbeats each 5 seconds to any client that connects to that SSE endpoint.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class SSE {
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Object>> streamEvents() {
        System.out.println("Someone's connected");
        
        Consumer <SignalType> disconnectionConsumer = new Consumer <SignalType> () {

            @Override
            public void accept(SignalType t) {
                System.out.println("Someone's dis(connected)");
            }

        };

        return Flux
            .interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .map(second -> {
                System.out.println("Sending heartbeat...");
                return ServerSentEvent.<Object> builder()
                    .event("heartbeat")
                    .build();
            })
            .doFinally(disconnectionConsumer)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
    }

}
```

Now if the client effectively ends the TCP connection, then the Flux will complete and *disconnectionConsumer* will be invoked as expected. However, if the client loses its connection to the server (be it disabling its network interface or losing its Wi-Fi/mobile signal) then the server doesn't detect that the connection went down and keeps sending heartbeats.

How can I detect the client lost its connection and complete the Flux when this happens? I suspect it might be related to Netty detecting the connection was lost while trying to receive TCP confirmation but not informing upstream but I'm not sure how to test it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you should remove this `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers it doesnt do what you think it does, parallel should only be used with CPU intensive tasks, and also you are using it wrong so its not doing anything for you atm.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I do not think you understand. Even if we remove it would still use parallel when we use interval.